# How to replace terminal title using sed in PS1 prompt string

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I've been at it for > 1 hr. and can't figure this out. Here's my `PS1` prompt string:

```
$ echo $PS1
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;this is the title\a\]
```

The terminal window title is the `this is the title` part. `\[\e]2;` marks the beginning of the title, and `\a\]` marks the end. See ["Customizing the terminal window title" here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title).

According to https://regex101.com/, the regex string `\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]` appears to match the title and its escape chars. See a demo of it here: https://regex101.com/r/okcx0T/1.

Therefore, this `sed` command should delete the title from the `PS1` string and print out the output, but it does not seem to match the title string at all! As you can see from `echo $PS1`, there is no difference:

```
$ echo $PS1 | sed -E "s|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||"
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;this is the title\a\]

$ echo $PS1
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;this is the title\a\]
```

**How can I replace this title string in the `PS1` variable, with or without `sed`?**

My `sed` command clearly works for simple matches. Watch this! `this is the title` is clearly deleted from the end of the `PS1` prompt string.

```
$ echo $PS1 | sed 's|this is the title||'
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;\a\]
```

I just can't seem to match the title string beginning and ending escape chars is all!

### References I've searched through while trying to solve this

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization#Customizing_the_terminal_window_title
2. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash/
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash
4. https://superuser.com/questions/1107680/how-to-use-sed-with-piping
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356958/sed-just-trying-to-remove-a-substring
6. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169207/remove-backslashes-from-a-text-file/169210#169210 - has some important-looking comments regarding escaping in bash, `'` vs `"`, etc.
7. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19491/how-to-specify-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes-in-grep
8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that double quotes allow the shell to replace `\\` by `\` - you can see this if you run the command with the shell's `-x` option:

```
$ set -x

$ echo foo | sed -E "s|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||"
+ echo foo
+ sed -E 's|\\[\e\]2;.*\a\\]||'
foo
```

It should work if you change to single quotes around the sed expression. The `-E` flag is not required ex. given

```
$ printf '%s\n'  "$ps1"
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;this is the title\a\]
```

then

```
$ set -x

$ printf '%s\n' "$ps1" | sed 's|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||'
+ sed 's|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||'
+ printf '%s\n' '\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ \[\e]2;this is the title\a\]'
\$SHLVL:2 \e[7m$(gs_git_show_branch)\e[m\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Comment: Thanks! Running `echo $PS1 | sed 's|\\\[\\e\]2;.*\\a\\\]||'` works! I didn't know about `set -x` before. It looks like `set +x` is how to "unset" or "undo" `set -x`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517162/how-to-undo-the-effect-of-set-e-which-makes-bash-exit-immediately-if-any-comm/3517181#3517181.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like `\\\[\\e\]2` is the smallest matching regex expression for the start of the title string. Total command: `echo $PS1 | sed 's|\\\[\\e\]2||'`. During debugging, I was repeatedly trying to just match the first `\ ` of the `\[\e]2;` marker, or just the `\[` part, or the `\[\e` or `\[\e]` part, but literally NONE of that is possible. **You must match all of `\[\e]2` at once, or nothing.** What does that mean? Is this a UTF-8 multi-byte unicode character or something? I thought (apparently incorrectly) it was a series of single-byte ASCII chars.